# How do I store unicode emoji to MYSQL in CodeIgniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, unicode, emoji, utf8mb4

I'm using codeigniter and trying to save  to a MYSQL database table

The error i'm getting is

```
Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x9A\x9A' for column 'post'
```

Comment: MYSQL does not support utf8mb4_unicode_ci before MYSQL 5.5. Maybe you can `base64_encode` the string before inserting.

Comment: See [_How to support full Unicode in MySQL databases_](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4).

Comment: Yes it's definitely a good solution to encode in base64 the string when you already have a database in use, to avoid new problem.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

1) Ensure you're using MYSQL 5.5 only then will you be able to change the collation to utf8mb4_something

2) Ensure table columns that are going to receive emoji have their collation set to utf8mb4_something

3) Edit your database.php config file

```
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8mb4';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci';
```

Comment: Actually, [you need to use MySQL 5.5.3 or later](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4). Older 5.5 versions don’t support `utf8mb4`.

Comment: I am using PHP version 5.6.22 and Mysql version 5.6.27. When I change from utf8 to utf8mb4 in codeigniter's database.php, I get this error : "Unable to set client connection character set: utf8mb4"

Comment: haaaa, this worked from me, thanks Man

Answer (score 5):

according this link

http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:http://andy-carter.com/blog/saving-emoticons-unicode-from-twitter-to-a-mysql-database

you can set your database char_set to utf8mb4 but all supported emojees are here:

✂️⤵️ ☺️☹️ ✊ ✌✋☝️ ✍❤️⛑ ⛹☘⭐️ ✨ ☄ ☀️ ⛅️ ☁️ ⛈ ⚡️ ❄️ ❄️ ☃ ⛄️  ☂ ☔️ 
☕️ 
⚽️ ⚾️  ⛳️  ⛷ ⛸  ⛹
✈️ ⛵️ ⛴ ⚓️ ⛽️ ⛲️ ⛰ ⛺️ ⛪️ ⛩
⌚️ ⌨ ☎️ ⏱ ⏲ ⏰ ⏳ ⌛️ ⚖ ⚒ ⛏ ⚙ ⛓ ⚔ ☠ ⚰ ⚱ ⚗ ⛱ ✉️ ✂️ ✒️ ✏️
❤️ ❣ ☮ ✝ ☪ ☸ ✡ ☯ ☦ ⛎ ♈️ ♉️ ♊️ ♋️ ♌️ ♍️ ♎️ ♏️ ♐️ ♑️ ♒️ ♓️ ⚛ ☢ ☣️ ✴️ ㊙️ ㊗️ ⛔️ ❌ ⭕️ ♨️ ❗️ ❕ ❓ ❔ ‼️ ⁉️ ⚜ 〽️ ⚠️ ♻️ ❇️ ✳️ ❎ ✅ ➿ Ⓜ️ ♿️ 0⃣ 1⃣ 2⃣ 3⃣ 4⃣ 5⃣ 6⃣ 7⃣ 8⃣ 9⃣ ▶️ ⏸ ⏯ ⏹ ⏺ ⏭ ⏮ ⏩ ⏪ ◀️ ⏫ ⏬ ➡️ ⬅️ ⬆️ ⬇️ ↗️ ↘️ ↙️ ↖️ ↕️ ↔️ ↪️ ↩️ ⤴️ ⤵️ #⃣ *⃣ ℹ️ 〰 ➰ ✔️ ➕ ➖ ➗ ✖️ © ® ™ ☑️ ⚪️ ⚫️ ▪️ ▫️ ⬛️ ⬜️ ◼️ ◻️ ◾️ ◽️ ♠️ ♣️ ♥️ ♦️‍
☺️ ☹️ ☝️ ✌ ✍ ❤️ ❣ ☠ ♨️ ✈️ ⌛️ ⌚️ ♈️ ♉️ ♊️ ♋️ ♌️ ♍️ ♎️ ♏️ ♐️ ♑️ ♒️ ♓️ ☀️ ☁️ ☂ ❄️ ⛄️ ☄ ♠️ ♥️ ♦️ ♣️ ▶️ ◀️ ☎️ ⌨ ✉️ ✏️ ✒️ ✂️ ↗️ ➡️ ↘️ ↙️ ↖️ ↕️ ↔️ ↩️ ↪️ ✡ ☸ ☯ ✝ ☦ ☪ ☮ ☢ ☣ ☑️ ✔️ ✖️ ✳️ ✴️ ❇️ ‼️ © ® ™ Ⓜ️ ▪️ ▫️ #⃣ *⃣ 0⃣ 1⃣ 2⃣ 3⃣ 4⃣ 5⃣ 6⃣ 7⃣ 8⃣ 9⃣ ⁉️ ℹ️ ⤴️ ⤵️ ♻️ ◻️ ◼️ ◽️ ◾️ ☕️ ⚠️ ☔️ ⏏ ⬆️ ⬇️ ⬅️ ⚡️ ☘ ⚓️ ♿️ ⚒ ⚙ ⚗ ⚖ ⚔ ⚰ ⚱ ⚜ ⚛ ⚪️ ⚫️ ⭐️ ⬛️ ⬜️ ⛑ ⛰ ⛪️ ⛲️ ⛺️ ⛽️ ⛵️ ⛴ ⛔️ ⛅️ ⛈ ⛱ ⛄️ ⚽️ ⚾️ ⛳️ ⛸ ⛷ ⛹ ⛏ ⛓ ⛩ ⭕️ ❗️ ❦ ♕ ♛ ♔ ♖ ♜ ☾ → ⇒ ⟹ ⇨ ⇰ ➩ ➪ ➫ ➬ ➭ ➮ ➯ ➲ ➳ ➵ ➸ ➻ ➺ ➼ ➽ ☜ ☟ ➹ ➷ ↶ ↷ ✆ ⌘ ⎋ ⏎ ⏏ ⎈ ⎌ ⍟ ❥ ツ ღ ☻

other emojees is not supported by utf8mb4

Comment: Thanks for the list ! But some emoji seems to not be handled by utf8_general